# Is there a efficient substitute to my django code?

Tags: python, django, django-views

## views.py

```
def redirectory(request):
    if request.user.is_Type_A:
        return redirect("is_Type_A_views")#This loads Type_A html page
    elif request.user.is_Type_B:
        return redirect("is_Type_B_views")#This loads Type_B html page
    elif request.user.is_Type_C:
        return redirect("is_Type_C_views")#This loads Type_C html page
```

Hi, i've created a log in function in django views.py that checks if
a user is_Type_A or is_Type_B or is_Type_C and logs in the user
to their custom pages based on their boolean fields True or False.
I didn't want to use filters because the account users must have access
to different function on the views.py and I didn't want to use
conditional statements on the html page because I dont want to
confuse myself and other people so I've created that code instead.
So its basically a redirectory function.

my question is, is that code efficient? can a Server use that single code
and handle multiple login requests? And if not, is there a more efficient substitute code that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this code is on the borderline of being readable/maintainable.

However, if you are going to have a few more users types I'd convert to a dictionary. It will require you to do some refactoring to move the user type from what it is now (a boolean, I guess `user.is_Type_A`) to some sort of a constant string (or `Enum`, preferably) as `request.user.user_type`,

then:

```
redirection_dict = {
    USER_TYPE_A: redirect("is_Type_A_views"),
    USER_TYPE_B: redirect("is_Type_B_views"),
    USER_TYPE_C: redirect("is_Type_C_views"),
}

def redirectory(request):
    return redirection_dict.get(request.user.user_type, '404')
```